# Django crispy form fields is not saving

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.7, django-crispy-forms, django-2.2

Im trying formatting with Django crispy forms, but its not possible to save.

first some code:

forms.py

```
class CreateForm_test(forms.Form): 
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))
    street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Street'}))
    number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number'}))
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Comment'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone'}))
    status = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Status'}))





class CrispyAddressForm(CreateForm_test):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'street',
            'number',
            Row(
                Column('comment', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),

                Column('phone', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                Column('status', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),


                css_class='form-row'
            ),

            Submit('submit', 'Submit')
        )
```

views.py

```
class CreateRegisterView(CreateView): 
    model = Register
    message = _("saved")
    form_class = CrispyAddressForm

    template_name = 'register_form.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        return reverse('home')
```

register_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I open the form in my Browser, I got this error

```
forms.py", line 36, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
[29/Feb/2020 18:40:13] "GET /Register/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 115893
```

I tried also with
 class CreateRegisterView(FormView): 
but then I get the same error to the views in this line  `form.instance.user = self.request.user`

Comment: You do not use a `ModelForm`, hence there is no `instance`.

Comment: ok, but when I change to forms.ModelForm, then I can see the form but its not saving. When I click on the submit button, the site is reloading, but nothing saved

Comment: do you see a POST request when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes, when I change to ModelForm, then I can see form in my Browser, but its not saving

Comment: but if you *submit* the form, it should *log* in the *server console* (not the browser) a POST request.

Comment: no, in console is nothing, only HTTP/1.1" state 200 for the same page

Comment: then likely the submit button is not working properly. You should inspect the HTML that is generated. The `<form>` tag should have as `method="post">`, and as action a URL to the same view.

Comment: Ok, I checked the generated HTML. I have `<form method="post">` and the button is ` <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-submit"> </form>`

Comment: it should have an `action="..."` tag attribute as well.

Comment: no, there is no action attribute

Comment: you forgot to specify the `form_action`. it should refer to the `CreateView`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used a `Form`, *not* a `ModelForm`. A simple `Form` has no `.instance`, and does not know anything about `.save()`, since the task of a `Form` is simply to process the `GET` or `POST` data, and do validation and cleaning. The `ModelForm` that is built on top of a `Form` can load, update and save model objects. You thus should subclass from a `ModelForm`, and provide a `Meta`:

```
class CreateForm_test(forms.ModelForm): 
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))
    street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Street'}))
    number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number'}))
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Comment'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone'}))
    status = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Status'})

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['name', 'street', 'number', 'comment', 'phone', 'status']
```

Furthermore as specified in the [documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#fundamentals), you need to specify the action in the helper:

```
class CrispyAddressForm(CreateForm_test):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_action = 'name_of_createview'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'street',
            'number',
            Row(
                Column('comment', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),

                Column('phone', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                Column('status', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),


                css_class='form-row'
            ),

            Submit('submit', 'Submit')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the main issue is I defined the fields twice. One time in models and one time in my forms.

Now this is working:
forms

```
class CreateForm_test(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['name', 'street', 'number', 'comment', 'phone', 'status']



class CrispyAddressForm(CreateForm_test):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
             Row(
                 Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-7 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Row(
                Column('street', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                Column('number', css_class='form-group col-md-1 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),

            Row(
                Column('comment', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Row(
                Column('phone', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit')
        )
```

views

```
class CreateRegisterView(CreateView):
    model = Register
    message = _("saved")
    form_class = CreateForm
    template_name = 'register_form.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        return reverse('home')
```

models

```
class Register(models.Model):
    CREATED = "C"
    DELETED = "D"
    STATUS = (
        (CREATED, _("Created")),
        (DELETED, _("Deleted")),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="author", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default=CREATED)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = ArticleQuerySet.as_manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, unique=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=6)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=42, null=True, unique=False, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Register")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Register")
        ordering = ("-timestamp",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

To understand, with crispyforms I have two options to formatting the form. First is this with the forms and the second direct in html.

When I change in the views to `form_class = CreateForm_test` and in html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Then is not longer working, the first example formatting in forms is working.In the second html I added only the field `name`, because only this is a mandatory field.

what is the difference that the html-formatting does not work? The form is visible in the browser but is not saving, no errors.